# All pairs shortest path in a connected graph with N nodes and N-1 edges

Tags: algorithm

I have a graph with N nodes (2 <= N <= 50000) and N is even. The values of the Nodes are always a number between 1 and N/2. It's granted that there is only one path between any pair of nodes and the weight of the edges is always one. How can i sum the distance of all nodes with equal value ?

This is a example:

The number inside the square is the value of the node and the small number below it its the identification of the node.

[image: Graph]

In this example the sum is distance(1,6) + distance(2,5) + distance(3,4) = 5

Floyd-Marshall or simple BFS its to expensive for this case.
I've seen that on DAGs is possible to get the shortest path with a topological sort. In this case it is a good approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you have a disjoint partition of your node set into pairs, represented by numbers from 1 to N/2. I'm also assuming that by "there is only one path between any pair of nodes" you really mean *any* pair and not just those of the same color.

In that case, first realize that your graph is a tree. So root it arbitrarily, and traverse it in depth-first order to compute the depth of all nodes. Note that for two nodes x and y, if their lowest common ancestor is l, then

```
distance(x, y) = distance(x, l) + distance(y, l) 
               = depth(x) - depth(l) + depth(y) - depth(l) 
               = depth(x) + depth(y) - 2*depth(l)
```

You can use [Tarjan's off-line LCA algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_lowest_common_ancestors_algorithm) to compute the LCA of all your pairs in (almost) linear time and compute the distances. You don't even need to store the LCAs in this case.

Runtime: O(n * α(n)) with naive disjoint set union, O(n) with the improvements from ["A Linear-Time Algorithm for a Special Case of
Disjoint Set Union", Gabow & Tarjan, 1983](http://scholar.colorado.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1257&context=csci_techreports)

Comment: Excellent solution. Way more efficient than a simple F/W.

Comment: @MarcoA. Thanks. What's F/W though?

Comment: Uh, Floyd-Warshall.. sorry :P